# Load URL from ImageView

Tags: parsing, url, imageview, uri, android-studio-3.4

I need to load a URL inside my app with the click of an ImageView. I get the app to load until I start trying to assign intents (on the MainActivity.java) to my ImageViews (on activity_main.xml).

I have tried ImageButton vs ImageView; and both come with their own set of issues I can't seem to find answers to. I finally gave up on the imageButton and am now trying my luck at ImageView. All Android components are up-to-date which includes the software itself, the gradle, and plugins.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/mainBackground"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/s"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/y"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/v"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/s"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/v"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/q"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/s"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/v"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.app.sega;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView img_s = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://southeastgeorgiatoday.com"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ImageView img_v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.q);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://us7.maindigitalstream.com/2780/"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.sega" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.southeastgeorgiatoday.com" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="us7.maindigitalstream.com/2780/" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The objective is to open the url of the intent inside the app with the click of the referenced ImageView.  But since including this intent script on the MainActivity.java it will not build, let alone install and launch. I have tried it both on the virtual and actual device via Android's Emulator and it will not install on either.

Here is the error message I get from the LogCat during the build process...

```
C:\Users\webwi\Documents\_MobileApps\SEGA\app\src\main\java\com\app\sega\MainActivity.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ^
  symbol:   variable img
  location: class MainActivity
C:\Users\webwi\Documents\_MobileApps\SEGA\app\src\main\java\com\app\sega\MainActivity.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        ^
  symbol:   variable img
  location: class MainActivity
2 errors
```

Also, it might be worth mentioning in both of the intent lines that begin with "**img**.setOnClickListener..." the 'img' before the '.' is red.

Obviously there is something wrong with my intents, I'm just not sure what? Any advice.

Comment: Did you post your complete MainActivity.java file? If so, you are missing two closing brackets.

Comment: @JoshSullivan yes, i had another look and two brackets at the end were missing. I added them and attempted to build again and my error message changed. I have updated the error message and MainActivity.java script in my original post.

Comment: You have ImageViews with IDs of s and v, yet you are looking for an ID of q. You also must rename your second ImageView variable; you are declaring the variable img twice.

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it but am still getting the following error..."C:\Users\webwi\Documents\_MobileApps\SEGA\app\src\main\java\com\app\sega\MainActivity.java:32: error: variable img is already defined in method onCreate(Bundle)
        ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.v);
                  ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Comment: Based on how it reads "...variable img is already defined in method onCreate(Bundle) ". It looks like I can only declare and ImageView once...or is there a way to rename each intent for each button based on that button. For example instead of " ImageView img = " maybe use "s_ImageView img = " . What do you think? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You cannot re-declare a variable after it has already been declared. Instead, do something like ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s); and ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.v);

Comment: okay, will do. I thought there might be a way of doing that; just wasn't sure how to go about it.

Comment: @JoshSullivan - I am finally back to my project and have tried what we mentioned above.  I've changed img to img_s in the first one and img_v in the second one. I've updated my script in the main post above for more details.  My error message changed, so I've updated that too. Also, it might be worth mentioning in both of the intent lines that begin with "img.setOnClickListener..." the 'img' before the '.' is red.

Comment: @JoshSullivan - fixed the img.setOnClicListener... error.  It seems that the line in reference should read... "img_s.setOnClickListener..." or "img_v.setOnClickListener..." depending on what I renamed them from in our earlier comments. I won't say that made me feel completely silly; I'll say it was a developer's humbling growing pain. Yeah, we'll call it that.

Comment: So now it is loading and installing the APIs, but when I click on the button it wants to open the native browser instead of opening it inside the app. But the buttons are loading the URLs and that's progress. Loading it inside the app is a question for another topic.  Thanks for your help Josh